# Using Playwright, page.url() is getting a previous url instead of the current url

Tags: automation, playwright

I'm testing the navigation on our website using `expect(page.url()).toContain('/nav');`.
When walking through the code I can clearly see that we hit that url string after the click.

I've tried putting my code into and outside of a promise granting the same error:

```
Expected substring: "/nav"
Received string:    "https://website.com/about"

      283 |     page.waitForNavigation();
      284 |     await page.hover('nav >> text=Nav');
      285 |     await page.click('nav >> text=Nav');
      286 |     console.log(page.url());
    > 287 |     expect(page.url()).toContain('/nav');
          |                        ^
      288 |
      289 |     page.click('text=Next Nav')
      290 |     expect(page.url()).toContain('/nextNav');
```

The link itself is a simple `<a href="/nav" class="list__item__link" data-v-0df6efc8>Nav</a>`.

The console log shows `https://website.com/about`.

Here's a snippet related to the comments:

```
////##OURSTORY##////
    page.hover('nav >> text=Our Story');
    page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.click('nav >> text=About');
    expect(page.url()).toContain('story');

    //await page.pause();

    await page.hover('nav >> text=Our Story');
    await page.hover('nav >> text=360° Wellness');
    await page.click('nav >> text=360° Wellness'); 
    console.log(page.url());
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    expect(page.url()).toContain('/360-wellness');
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the url to a string?

Comment: If `url()` already returns a string, then perhaps the missing `await` before `page.url()` could solve it? Please let us know if that works.

Comment: I added an `await` before the `page.url()` and it didn't help. My IDE even says it's not needed. `page.url()` already converts it to a string, it's a built in functionality.

Comment: I see. And you're positive that the url actually has that `/nav` text? have you tested this with `headless: false`?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. When using `await page.pause()` and stepping through the code I can visibly see the `/nav` in the url and then get the error above. And I always run my tests in `headless: false`.

Comment: Hmm, weird. How about trying `expect(page.url()).toBe('https://website.com/nav');` or `toEqual('url-with-nav')`?

Comment: Okay, I tried `toBe('https://website.com/nav')` and it yielded the same result.

Comment: This is strange. Is the URL you're testing publicly available? If you could share it, perhaps I could try to reproduce it locally and debug.

Comment: Sorry it took awhile for me to respond, I was out with the flu. The site is https://ariix.newage.com/ when you hover over "Our Story" at the top in the nav you'll see "360° Wellness", that for some reason has trouble when all the rest work just fine.

Comment: I couldn't add my solution here in the comments, so I posted an answer with what worked for me. Do try it out and please let us know if that works for you as well?

Comment: Also, I hope you're better health wise now. Excuse me for being insensitive and not inquiring before :P

Answer (score 2):

You may cover it in [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to avoid race condition as `Promise.all` waits till all promises are resolved declared inside it.

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
          page.waitForNavigation(),
          page.click('nav >> text=360° Wellness')
     ]);


await expect(page.url()).toContain('/360-wellness');
```

Source: https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations

Answer (score 2):

Playwright API for this is `waitForURL`, like this:

```
await page.goto('/');
await page.waitForURL('**/auth/login');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project that requires the same output as this question.
Just would like to add up what works for me is to make an interaction before getting the `page.url()`

for me, I did an interaction like clicking a search bar

```
  await page.locator('input[placeholder=\'Choose starting point, or click on the map...\']').click();
```

then call

```
page.url();
```

I couldn't explain further as I am still new in this, just would like to share what works for me. Hope this helps for anyone working on these days.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was a little wary of using `page.waitForNavigation()` from the start, so I gave it a second thought about needing to use it here. Turns out, we don't really need it. Considering load time variations, I added a `waitForSelector()` which should allow it 30 seconds (or you could do `setTimeout` to set a custom wait time).

Also, here's a little something about the `waitForNavigation()` method -

`page.waitForNavigation()` returns a promise that resolves only after the navigation has finished. The documentation mentions -

> In case of navigation to a different anchor or navigation due to
> [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) usage, the navigation will resolve with `null`.

Since the site development approach can be ambiguous, its perhaps better to steer clear of using the said function. Especially since it also states -

> It is useful for when you run code which will indirectly cause the
> page to navigate

... which in all honesty, I don't clearly understand the use case for.

Anyway, here is what worked; the full `test.spec.ts` file -

```
import { Page } from "playwright-core";

describe("Test Suite for a patient random guy on Stack Overflow", () => {
  it("Test Gen: [URL Text] Testing the correct URL path", async () => {
    let page: Page;
    page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://ariix.newage.com");
    page.hover("nav >> text=Our Story");
    await page.waitForSelector("nav >> text=About");
    await page.click("nav >> text=About");
    console.log(page.url());
    expect(page.url()).toContain("story");
    //await page.pause();
    await page.hover("nav >> text=Our Story");
    await page.waitForSelector("nav >> text=360° Wellness");
    await page.click("nav >> text=360° Wellness");
    console.log(page.url());
    expect(page.url()).toContain("/360-wellness");
  });
});
```

And it seems to do/print what you were aiming to -

[image]

Hopefully this solves this issue at your end. Let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
       old_url = page.url
       page.wait_for_url(lambda url: old_url != url, timeout=1.5*1000)
       print(f'Go to URL : {page.url}')
```

Most of the time it works
But sometimes it doesn't
So I try to find some element before get current URL

```
page.wait_for_selector(selector='//body')
print(f'Go to URL : {page.url}')
```